# Rxjava2: Map exception into Single<Boolean>

Tags: rx-java2

I'm trying to write a method the returns `Single<Boolean>` and it's functionality is to check whether an HTTP server is alive.

so it sends a ping to server and it works fine in case server is online, but in case server is down it returns an exception which is propagated to `subscribe`.
I would like to catch the exception and map it into `false` and return internally from `isAlive` method.

Here is my attempt:

```
public Single<Boolean> isAlive()
  {
    return client().get(HEALTH_CHECK_PATH) //
        .rxSend() //
        .onErrorReturnItem(null) //
        .map(response -> {
          return response.statusCode() == HttpResponse.HTTP_STATUS_NO_CONTENT;
        });
  }
```

I tried to return `null` and on the `map` check for null and return a boolean accordingly - map Single doesn't handle `null`....any idea?
Thanks.

**EDIT-1**

I've tried:

`.onErrorResumeNext(err -> Single.just(Boolean.FALSE))`

it doesn't compile..

Comment: `null` values are not allowed in RxJava2 observer chains. You might consider using `onErrorReturnNext( Single.just( FALSE ) )` instead.

Comment: Did you mean `onErrorResumeNext` ?? if so - it doesn't compile.
I

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing:

```
public Single<Boolean> isAlive()
  {
    return client().get(HEALTH_CHECK_PATH) //
        .rxSend() //
        .map(response -> response.statusCode() == HttpResponse.HTTP_STATUS_NO_CONTENT)//
        .onErrorResumeNext(err -> Single.just(Boolean.FALSE));
  }
```